# show DD.MM.YYYY date + X days

Tags: javascript

Hi I have a code that shows date + 5 days in DD.MM format

Please help me to add current year to this code. DD.MM.YYYY

Year also should be  like day and month and not this way `+  "2017"`

```
<script>
function get(dday) {
 var    newdate = new Date();
     newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate()+dday);
return newdate.getDate() +  "." + ''+['01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12'][newdate.getMonth()];
}
  </script>


<span><script  type="text/javascript">document.write(get(5));</script></span>
```

Comment: I've removed your [tag:java] question tag. Please understand that Java and JavaScript are two completely different languages, that questions tags and question titles are the most important parts of your question, and that if either are off, you won't get the correct experts to see your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Date.getFullYear` returns the full year.

```html
<script>
function get(dday) {
 var newdate = new Date();
 newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate()+dday);
 function pad(value){
  return ("0"+value).substring(value<10?0:1);
 }
 return [pad(newdate.getDate()),pad(newdate.getMonth()+1),newdate.getFullYear()].join(".");
}
  </script>


<span><script  type="text/javascript">document.write(get(5));</script></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
<script>
function get(dday) {
 var    newdate = new Date();
     newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate()+dday);
return newdate.getDate() +  "." + ''+['01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12'][newdate.getMonth()]+"."+newdate.getFullYear();
}
  </script>


<span><script  type="text/javascript">document.write(get(5));</script></span>
```

This outputs : `24.03.2017`